# Powershell Get-PnPFile Access denied error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to download a file from a Teams Sharepoint site using Powershell.
I'm using this code:

```
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline 

#Config Variables
$SiteURL = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/"
$FileRelativeURL = "/sites/MyTeam/documents/General/test.pptx"
$DownloadPath ="C:\temp"

Try {
    #Connect to PNP Online
    Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -SPOManagementShell  #Need modern login because of MFA     
    #Get-PnPConnection
    #Get-PnPContext

    #powershell download file from sharepoint online
    Get-PnPFile -Url $FileRelativeURL -Path $DownloadPath -Filename "test.pptx" -AsFile
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

However, when I run this, I always get an error:

```
Access denied. You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource
```

I am owner of the Team, and the file.
What kind of permissions do I need for this?

I've also read on the internet that some people, use slightly different URLs. Like this:

```
$SiteURL = "https://xxxxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/MyTeam"
```

This results in a different error:

```
File not found
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What happens if you do `$conn = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -SPOManagementShell -ReturnConnection` and use that in `Get-PnPFile -Url $FileRelativeURL -Connection $conn -Path $DownloadPath -Filename "test.pptx" -AsFile` ?

Comment: Same error (Access denied). Weirdly, the login popup hasn't shown up anymore for a while now, however when I output the $conn object, it does contain data.

Comment: Perhaps the connection is now cached because you do not seem to disconnect using `Disconnect-PnPOnline` Try disconnecting first and start afresh